# Why am I getting FileNotFoundError?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import os
files = [file for file in os.listdir("./Sales_Data")]

all_months_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/My pc/Desktop/Playing with Pandas/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data.csv' + file)
    all_months_data = pd.concat([all_months_data + df])
```

What I am doing is merge all data from a folder into one CSV.
I am getting this error :

```
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:/Users/My pc/Desktop/Playing with Pandas/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data.csvSales_April_2019.csv' does not exist: b'C:/Users/My pc/Desktop/Playing with Pandas/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data.csvSales_April_2019.csv'"
```

I need help.

Comment: This already is a complete file_path: `C:/Users/My pc/Desktop/Playing with Pandas/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data.csv`, adding the variable `file` to this does not make any sense

Comment: Just checking, correct me if I'm wrong, but you're trying to open `'Sales_Data.csv' + file` and you're wondering why the error message says that `Sales_Data.csvSales_April_2019.csv` doesn't exist?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am trying to do

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests by itself:

```
Sales_Data.csvSales_April_2019.csv' does not exist:
```

You are appending the `file` variable to already complete path of the file.

Remove the hardcoded filename from the below path:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/My pc/Desktop/Playing with Pandas/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data.csv' + file)
```

Use this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/My pc/Desktop/Playing with Pandas/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/' + file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. All I had to do is to put another backward slash after the path. So for everyone who faces similar issue. This could help